# xpath php attributes not working?

Tags: xpath, simplexml, php

Getting this error

> Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

I have found multiple answers to this on SO, but none of them seem to solve my problem?

Here is the XML:

```
<Routes>
    <Route type="source" name="incoming">
    </Route>
<Routes>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement('routingConfig.xml', null, true);
class traverseXML {

    function getData() {
        global $doc;
        $routeCount = count($doc -> xpath("Route")); //this value returns correctly
        $routeArr = array();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $routeCount; $i++) {

            $name = $doc -> Route[$i] -> attributes() -> name;

            array_push($routeArr, $name);

        }
        return $routeArr;

    }

    }
    $traverseXML = new traverseXML;
    var_dump($traverseXML -> getData());
```

I understand what the error means, but how is it a non-object? How do I return the `name` attribute of `Routes/Route[1]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$doc` is `<Routes>`. Trying to get `->Routes` from it is trying to get

```
<Routes>
    <Routes>
```

You need to do `$doc->Route[$i]`. Errors like this are less frequent when you name your variable after the document root:

```
$Routes = new SimpleXMLElement('routingConfig.xml', null, true);
```

Also, your XML is invalid. The Routes element is not closed.

In addition, you don't need the XPath. SimpleXML is traversable, so you can foreach over all the routes by doing

```
foreach ($Routes->Route as $route) {
```

And `attributes()` returns an array, so you cannot chain `->name` off it but must access it with square brackets. But it's not necessary to use `attributes()` anyway because you can get attributes from SimpleXmlElements directly via square brackets, e.g.

```
echo $route['name'];
```

Here is an example that will print "incoming":

```
$xml = <<< XML
<Routes>
    <Route type="source" name="incoming"/>
</Routes>
XML;

$routes = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($routes->Route as $route) {
    echo $route['name'];
}
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/0dHylkPk)

If you want to do it with XPath, you can collect all the attributes in an array like this:

```
$routeNames = array_map('strval', $Routes->xpath('/Routes/Route/@name'));
```

Yes, it's just that one line :)

As for your class:

[Don't use `global`. Forget it exists.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527) If you want to have a class, inject the dependency, e.g. do

```
class Routes
{
    private $routes;

    public function __construct(SimpleXmlElement $routes)
    {
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public function getRouteNames()
    {
        return array_map('strval', $this->routes->xpath('/Routes/Route/@name'));
    }
}

$routes = new Routes(simplexml_load_string($xml));
print_r($routes->getRouteNames());
```

[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dEElo2)

Comment: Thank you! I actually had the right XML document, but screwed up my paste. This is much cleaner than my route.